# Concentration of caffeine in physiologically relevant setting

Tags: pharmacology, cell-cycle

Caffeine is known to overcome [G2/M](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18444173) [(and possibly other types of)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16709440) cell cycle arrest through its [effects on DNA repair machinery](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9870697) and is used as a positive control in studies of cell cycle arrest. In [this paper](http://jvi.asm.org/content/79/4/2058.long#sec-9), for example, researchers use concentrations of caffeine in the 1-4 mM range to overcome nocodazole-mediated arrest. Is this a physiologically relevant concentration?

I found a lot of interesting caffeine data including the [LD50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine#Toxicity) (estimated to be around 150-200 mg/kg) but have not been able to turn up any good numbers on reasonable concentrations that might be found in a human.

Comment: To make sure I understand your question right: You are looking for the physiologically occurring caffeine concentrations in the human body? For example after consuming coffee?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's figure it out. Suppose an adult with an average blood volume of 5 L (5000 mL) drinks a cup of strong coffee with 100 mg of caffeine in it. Given caffeine's formula weight of 194.19 g/mol, and assuming 100% of the caffeine is in the blood stream, its concentration (from [this awesome calculator page](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/Molarityform.cfm) from Graphpad, the makers of Prism) would be approximately 103 µM, or 10-40 times **less** than what's being used in the experiments you cite.

Of course, this is overcoming drug-mediated cell cycle arrest, so its possible that a lower concentration is needed to jump-start physiologically-arrested cells.